# Testing Randomness of Permutation Sequences

Tags: algorithms, random-permutations

Maybe this question is too simple, but I couldn't find anything that is concerned with measuring how random a sequence of permutations of $n$ elements( w.l.o.g. of the numbers $\lbrace 1,\ \dots,\ n \rbrace\ $) is.

For sequences of numbers or points there are quite a few tests available, that have to be passed to qualify as sufficiently random, i.e. lacking discernible patterns.

> **Questions:**
>
> - is there something like the [Diehard Tests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diehard_tests) for sequences of permutations of a fixed set of elements?
> - which random permutation generators are considered "safe"?

Comment: I think you need to provide more details. For instance, what is your sampling space? If you are just selecting a member of a set with n! elements with uniform probability, is this problem not trivial? What do you mean by generators?

Comment: @thedude I don't want to select just one member, but a *representative* sample of manageable size, analogous to asking 1000 carefully selected people instead of several millions to get representative answers. In the same manner I want a set of *representative* permutations, of which I can test certain properties and be sure, that the results are not much different when performing the tests on all permutations. A generator is an algorithm or device, that produces sequences of permutations.

Comment: @thedude, a lot of effort has gone into solving the "trivial" problem of selecting a member of a finite set with uniform probability. Keyphrase: "uniform random number generator".